# VB.net load dynamic DLL created in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, dll, dynamic-loading

A simple dynamic loading of DLLs originally written in VC++ but called at VB is as following:

```
Public Declare Sub Increase Lib "mylib.dll" (ByRef a As Double)
```

What if the DLL code is also written in VB. Then how to load it? Lets assume the DLL code is:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub Increase(ByRef a As double)
        a=a+1
        MsgBox("new value ="+a)
    End Sub
End Class
```

My concern is how to load and call `Increase` from class `Class1`.

Please ignore small typos of me.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant I got nothing out of it. I am a VB beginner. Could you please write it in one line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DLL was compiled from .NET code (VB.NET or C#) then you have two options:

1) Add a reference to the DLL in Visual Studio. This gives you the benefit of having intellisense autocomplete and other help from the IDE. I would suggest doing this unless you have a strong reason to do otherwise.

To do this, first compile Class1 in a Class Library project, then create the new project in Visual Studio that you wish to use the DLL with. In Visual Studio right click on your project icon, click Add Reference, and then choose Browse. Locate your DLL, and then add it to your project. Once you do this, you will be able to use your classes and functions. It will be available as ProjectName.Class1.Increase().

2) Load the DLL dynamically at runtime, using reflection. This has several disadvantages, such as not being able to use intellisense, but is useful if you are planning on making plugins or have embedded DLLs within your own DLL. To do this, you would want to follow the advice of @HansPassant and review the link he gave you, specifically this statement:

> Use Assembly to define and load assemblies, load modules that are listed in the assembly manifest, and locate a type from this assembly and create an instance of it.

The Assembly class in Reflection allows us to dynamically load, compile, and run almost any .NET assemblies. If you are just beginning in VB, you will find this a challenge - but reflection is worthwhile getting to know. You should be comfortable with Reflection and generally understand what you are doing before you start diving too deep into dynamic loading.